# How to display Folder name in URL differently OR hide Folder name in URL in cakephp?

Tags: php, url, cakephp

I have tried to routing file. But just want to change the name of the folder or hide name of the folder in URL. Whereas routing changed are dealing with controller and model etc and not the cakephp-folder.
Also I don't want to move my entire project into root.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

Comment: You are probably looking for this: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/

Comment: If you can configure your server, you should take a look at "how to create a virtual host". Else you can try to create a subdomain that point to your cakephp folder.